# I want to intercept a given program before it runs and run my own program first

Tags: windows

I'm going to work with Python 3, mainly interested in Windows for a start. If it makes a difference, then Windows 10 specifically.

Example of what I want to happen:

1. User starts my script.
2. User decides to blacklist the game Dota 2.
3. User tries to open Dota 2.
4. Because Dota 2 is on the blacklist, my script runs instead of Dota 2.
5. After my script is done, Dota 2 either runs or doesn't run, depending on what my script chooses. This will ultimately be controlled by User.
6. User closes my script.
7. User tries to open Dota 2.
8. Dota 2 opens right away without interruptions.

---

The last three lines is to signify that there needs to be a way of turning it on and off, so not a permanent solution. My base assumption is that once I know how to do the first part, the second part will be easy. I still put it in there for clarification.

I really just want to know how to gain access to intercepting the programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 3. User tries to open Dota 2.
> 4. Because Dota 2 is on the blacklist, my script runs instead of Dota 2.

Windows' [Image File Execution Options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/04/28/image-file-execution-options/) lets you cause your program to be run whenever an executable of your choice is started.

Suppose we want to run `C:\My Folder\new app.exe` whenever the user tries to start `C:\Windows\old app.exe`.  To accomplish this, run the following command:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\old app.exe" /v Debugger /d "C:\My Folder\new app.exe" /f
```

**Note:** If a key named `old app.exe` doesn't exist (likely), this command will create it.

This creates a new Registry key with the name of the program to be "hijacked" and creates a new string value named **Debugger** that has its data set to the path of the replacement executable.  This can be any executable file, including `.CMD` batch scripts.

The change takes effect immediately.  Now whenever an executable named `old app.exe` is run, Windows will start `C:\My Folder\new app.exe` instead.

To return everything to normal, delete the `old app.exe` key:

```
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\old app.exe" /f
```

Simply incorporate these commands into your script to accomplish your desired outcome.

Comment: Just quick question(s), what if the app we want to run isn't in C:\Windows? What if it's on another hard disc or in another folder of C? Does this also work for things that aren't really applications, like files?

Comment: @GoodDay You can point this to any location you want, so long as it's accessible to all users that will run it. You have to point to something that's executable. If in doubt, just do a quick test with your desired file. Since the changes take effect immediately it's easy to test your settings.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it, you wrote: `C:\Windows\old app.exe`, that indicates to me that we're working in `C:\Windows\` at a minimum.

And when I went into the regedit to check, maybe I'm missing something, but I can't really find everything that I'm looking for.

Comment: Well of course that was an example.  You could set the data for the **Debugger** value to `C:\My Folder\MyScript.cmd` if you wanted to and it will work.  Does that help?

Comment: Ok, let's make an example, I think it will be clear for me then: Let's say the app I want to intercept is in K:\programs\test\old_app.exe , then what do I do?

Comment: That's only half of it.  What do you want to *actually* run when the user executes `K:\programs\test\old_app.exe`?

Comment: Ok, I have now played around with this a bunch and I'm more and more starting to think that it doesn't work as intended. I also have some questions.

1. So basically, there's no directory, it's just assumed that every file that would be in this folder is the only file with that name?
2. What do you mean by non-.exe working? I couldn't get anything other than .exe to work, either as the old nor new file. For old file nothing happens, and for new file it bugs.

Comment: 3. It doesn't do what I wanted to do. Instead, it seems to try to run old file as "open with" new file. If I try to redirect emacs.exe to notepad++.exe it will copy the opening message of emacs. If I try to redirect it to paint it just bugs.
4. If we would get it to work as intended, then how do I know which program they tried to run? I guess a not very elegant way would be to direct it through a unique for every program.
5. What do I do if there was already something in that registry folder? It seems to delete everything. But it keeps the empty folder, which bugs when you try to view it.