# Overriding specific exe with another one in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, application-launch

I am running a Windows 7 machine. Recently I found an application that did this:

I had `a.exe` prior to the installation. The application installs `b.exe` on my computer. Also it sets things up, so that every time I execute `a.exe`, `b.exe` is executed instead of it. Also I am sure that I am executing exactly `a.exe` when this happens. Moreover renaming any valid *exe* file in any location to `a.exe` and executing it will result in execution of `b.exe`. For invalid *exe* files (e.g. text files) this procedure will result in error.

My question is, how is this possible to do? And is it not quite big security risk? Also I am running Windows 7.

Comment: When you rename an exe to `a.exe` is the content of that exe file then being changed in any way?

Comment: If you look under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\ and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options is there a Key for a.exe? If so is there a debugger value?

Comment: @SpiderPig No the file remains unchanged the whole time.

Comment: @HelpingHand Actually yes. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\a.exe` there is a string key **Debugger** that contains path to `b.exe`. This is it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your executable is being hijacked by "Image File Execution Options"

[Image File Execution Options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/04/28/image-file-execution-options/) is a feature of Windows that lets you force a different program to run instead of the actual executable started by the user. This is useful, for example if you want to [run a batch file before a program starts](https://superuser.com/q/1201773/213131), regardless of how that program is executed. But it can cause problems when you're not aware the feature is being used since Windows makes no explanation for why `b.exe` starts when `a.exe` was executed.

Fortunately, managing this feature isn't difficult.  You'll find all of the program "intercepts" in the Registry here:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
```

The child keys are named for the executable that will have it's startup redirected. There are many keys here by default that should be left alone. Simply search for a key matching the name of your executable `a.exe` and then confirm that key contains a value named `Debugger`.  This value specifies the `b.exe` executable that will be started instead of `a.exe`.

To stop the unwanted behavior, either delete the Debugger value, or the entire a.exe key