# macOS: Intercepting program execution

Tags: macos, process

I want to intercept an execution of arbitrary executable. Suppose there is a binary `/usr/bin/binary`. Whenever somebody launches that binary, I want to start my own executable instead. From it I want to decide should original binary be started or not. Ultimately, I want to insert my shim between original binary and the user.

Similar Windows question has been asked: [I want to intercept a given program before it runs and run my own program first](https://superuser.com/questions/1201773/i-want-to-intercept-a-given-program-before-it-runs-and-run-my-own-program-first)

I have admin rights to the system. I cannot relocate original binaries to other places though.

**UPD** as asked by @dirkt:

- there will be a hard coded list of binaries I'd like to intercept.

Comment: Move `/usr/bin/binary` to some other location, rename your own executable to `/usr/bin/binary`, start original binary in other location if necessary.

Comment: Good way, but this will cause a lot of work. Imagine there are 2000+ binaries I want to intercept. Moving them to other places is a bit tedious, and it won't be possible to upgrade them easily (e.g. if they are installed via `brew`)

Comment: You didn't say "2000+ binaries", you said "a binary" (as in "a single one"). Please update this question with the new information, this makes it a very different question - you need to intercept at the OS level somehow. Please also specify how you are going to decide which binaries you want to intercept, and which you don't. A set of regular expressions? Something else?

Comment: Yeah, I've written "arbitrary executable", and as an example provided "a binary" `/usr/bin/binary`. I think if there would be a way to intercept a single binary execution, then it will be possible to extend this to any number of executables.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER** : i'm a total ignorant in MacOS world, but i would give you some way i would do that under GNU/Linux... may be it will help.

Hmmm... I would have reply just like @dirkt (aka a wrapper called `binary` that would point to `binary.real`) but:

1. If user is aware of your mechanism, then he could launch `binary.real` directly.
2. You have to duplicate this mechanism for every program you want to "monitor".

So let's dig a bit somewhere else...

### The kernel module

On GNU/Linux world, i would have write a kernel module to hook on exec system call and implement the ACL as you want.... but this is a bit overkilled.
It looks like it's possible to develop kernel modules for Mac OS... But i don't know if Apple allows that kind of hack.

### The LD_PRELOAD hack

Using the well known `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism (that looks to be `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` [on your world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514783/what-is-the-exact-equivalent-to-ld-preload-on-osx)), you can rewrite any C function of any library of you system. 
So you simply have to:

1. Write a dynamic library that implement exec*().
2. Implement your ACL.
3. Ensure that every user session (graphical ones, terminal) are launched with your library preloaded thanks to the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`)

Et voilà !

Comment: macOS prevents `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` for some binaries.

Comment: But i guess it's only super-user or system dedicated binaries such as updater, licence checks, etc... right ? Any documentation related to this issue ?